# Flutter app stuck on splash screen on release

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, flutter-android

I'm facing a weird issue with the release build of my flutter app. The splash screen will be on forever and the app won't show the home screen. However, when I run it using `flutter run --release` the app works fine.

Here's my `AndroidManifest`

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@layout/splash_screen"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is my `MainActivity.kt`

```
package ...

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreen
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant




class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun provideSplashScreen(): SplashScreen? {
        return AppSplashScreen()
    }
}

class AppSplashScreen: SplashScreen{
    override fun createSplashView(context: Context, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.splash_screen, null, false)
    }

    override fun transitionToFlutter(onTransitionComplete: Runnable) {
        onTransitionComplete.run();
    }

}
```

This is my `Application.java`

```
package ...;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;


public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Also, when I install the app on my phone I see the same issue, but when I run it from flutter it works fine.
Note: iOS version works fine

Comment: are you fetching any data from internet on splash screen?

Comment: @Shanto During the main function I do initialize the firebase app and I do get some data from firebase. But that during the main function

Comment: does home screen navigation depends on the data that you get from firebase?

Comment: @Shanto No, basically I get the user info if the user signed in and that's it.

Comment: have you included internet permission in android manifest?

Comment: @Shanto Yes I did

Comment: have you added SHA certificate fingerprints on firebase for your release build?

Comment: @Shanto Yes I have added that to my firebase settings

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you want to implement native splash screen in flutter.

Please check below code for `MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        Thread.sleep(3000)
    }
}
```

Please check below code for `styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please check below code for `launch_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_splash"/>
</layer-list>
```